# how to secure my router and internet connection?

Tags: networking, router, security

let's say there is a mole in my isp, and is not afraid of court, and compromised my isp as well and i don't want comlaint filing but just secure my router from his access. he has internal access to the isp, and my isp provided username which is usually the telephone number and the password which is default. so how can i change the default password, not the router password which is admin which i already did, but he doesn't need that to on/off my connection at will. can i change that password. when i forgot my router password, which i forgot, during reset i have my isp provided username and password, so what is that called? is that pppoe which is different from router page password. 
one more:how can i disable and make it unusable for that hacker(rare situation-but practically possible) who is inside my isp to ward him off.

Comment: How you change the password is service provider specific.

Comment: how do i secure my router, not from general public-which i did my adding router password,but after the compromised isp, so that the isp invader hacker himself cannot access my router. i can't complain since my isp is corrupt and cannot change, and is compromised.

Comment: no,not the router pass, which i can change, but the pppoe one.

Comment: Assuming you use a router that isn't provided by your ISP, they can only access it via the same method you would, and that would only be if it's accessible to external administration, which is disabled by default. But that's irrelevant, they provide your access credentials (via pppoe or whatever) and have far more control over that side of things than you.

Comment: Similar to your credentials to any site. For example, Facebook don't need your password to access all of your information, it's all on their server. As is all your internet traffic with your ISP

Comment: Relevant: [How to secure a modem/ wifi router without login?](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/108021/2138) -- Also more generally, try searching [security.se] for [posts containing 'malicious isp'](http://security.stackexchange.com/search?q=malicious+isp).

Comment: Easiest way to make your Internet "unusable for hacker" is unplug your router...

Comment: but can it be made to appear that i used that when someone else did? so can the router be used in opposite direction of router towards isp, instead of inward direction towards me? will my name come if it's used from outside the router line-away from me? or only the inside clients-USERS can use it. what do they need to feed to access my router(since my router passwd is secure).

Comment: unplug router=switch off modem or not??

Comment: uint128_t how do i unplug my router?

Comment: pull the power plug

Comment: You can't secure your internet connection from your ISP.  This question is unanswerable.

Answer (score 1):

This is something which is ISP specific - you would need to get in contact with your ISP and get them to change it for you - although I'm not sure this helps you all that much.  The password you are wanting to change is the PPP authentication password.

It is highly probable that you are not able to change the authentication password to something that a suitably skilled network administrator at an ISP can't change or modify.

Indeed, if you think of it, you are, in effect asking how you can lock the ISP out of part of the network they control... you can't prevent him changing the details if he has compromised the ISP.